Safari local PDF: Dark Mode with Dark Reader
How to Enable Dark Mode for Local PDFs in Safari Using Dark Reader?
Problem:
When I open PDF files in Safari, they load with a file:/// URL, which prevents Dark Reader from applying a dark theme. When I open PDFs directly from a website, Dark Reader works fine, but it doesn’t apply the dark mode to local PDFs. I’d like to open these local PDFs in a way that allows Dark Reader to apply its dark theme.

What I’ve Tried:
I attempted to serve the PDF via a local server using:
python -m http.server

and then opened it in Safari using http://localhost:8000/file.pdf, but this didn’t work as expected (the same problem as the file:/// link)
Question:
Is there a way to adjust Safari’s handling of file:/// URLs for PDFs, or another method to open these files as a regular link so Dark Reader can apply its dark theme? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
